# Type providers are not available for .net 2.0/3.x?

Tags: .net, f#, type-providers

When I try to create project for .net 2.0 or .net 3.5 I can't use any types related to type providers. According to references VS is using F# 3.0 for .NET 2.0. So type providers aren't available for .net 2.0/3.x? It's available only under .net 4.0 and newer?

P.S. BTW FSharp.Core.dll for .net 2.0 (located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\v2.0\FSharp.Core.dll`) doesn't contain types related to type providers.

Actualy I always thought that F# team made all features of F# 2.0 and F# 3.0 available for .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you're authoring a type provider, it must use .Net 4 - keep in mind that type providers participate in design-time, which means they get loaded into the Visual Studio process (which is already running .Net 4.5).

Answer (score 1):

No, only .Net 4.5+ (there is only 4.5 for now).